# How to solve a system of differential equations with complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

So I have a general understanding of how to do these types of problems but I do not know how to get rid of the complex numbers. I found that the eigenvalues are 3i and -3i and the eigenvectors are [(-2/5 + 1/5 i), (1)] and [(-2/5 - 1/5 i), (1)].

The general equation would be v1*c1*cos(3t) + v2*c2*sin(3t) where I would then attempt to find the constants, however, when multiplying the vectors, more complex numbers are introduced and my answer must be real only.

How do I isolate the real part only?

Comment: Observe that the two eigenvectors are complex conjugates. Does this suggest any linear combinations of them that have all real components?

Comment: amd, not sure what you mean by the linear combination of them? Am I suppose to find other vectors to use?

Comment: That’s it exactly. The real and imaginary parts of either of the eigenfunction solutions are also linearly-independent solutions of the differential equation (verify this). You can use a linear combination of those as the general solution. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549838/finding-solutions-to-a-system-of-differential-equations-with-complex-eigenvalues?rq=1 from the related questions at right if you don’t remember this from your course material.

Comment: You literally took a screen shot of your homework?

Comment: orange, is that against the rules? I'd rather avoid typos and formatting issues.